# How to use multiple GET arguments in cURL in CMD?

Tags: curl, cmd, command-prompt

I need to use cURL in Windows Command Prompt, my URL has multiple GET arguments and the & symbol, that separates the arguments, is interfering. For example, if I did `curl https://example.com/?get=1&get2=1 > file.txt` then CMD would say something like **"'get2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."** I have looked online for potential work-arounds but I've had no luck. I've tried using URL encoding on the & symbol but that doesn't work, I have tried passing the -d argument in cURL to signify a GET parameter but as I said, no luck. If anyone has nay suggestions then they are most welcome! I am also open to using another program other than cURL as long as it can be used via CMD and can output the webpage's contents to a file. 
Many thanks for all future responses!

Comment: Did you try doublequoting your URL, `"%__APPDIR__%curl.exe" --url "https://example.com/?get=1&get2=1" 1> "file.txt"`? Or if you're not using the Windows 10 built-in version, `"P:\ath\To\curl.exe" "https://example.com/?get=1&get2=1" 1> "file.txt"`.

Comment: I will try that now. curl.exe --url "https://example.com/?get=1&get2=1" > file.txt works, Thanks!

Comment: I've removed your latest edit, htt5041. The question area is not an appropriate location for answers. I have additionally included my commented advice as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your URL contains characters which are problematic to `cmd.exe`, I would suggest that you protect those using doublequotes around your URL string:

```batch-file
curl "https://example.com/?get=1&get2=1" > file.txt
```

More correctly, if you're using the Windows 10 built-in version of cURL:

```batch-file
"%__APPDIR__%curl.exe" --url "https://example.com/?get=1&get2=1" 1> "file.txt"
```

Or if you're using another version of cURL:

```batch-file
"P:\ath\To\curl.exe" "https://example.com/?get=1&get2=1" 1> "file.txt"
```

The `P:\ath\To` and `.exe` parts of the command can be removed, if you're certain that the cURL executable is located within the current directory, or within `%PATH%` and that the `%PATHEXT%` variable has not been modified, to remove the `.EXE` extension.